# SublimeHaskell not seeing extra-deps when running checks

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, haskell-platform

New to Haskell, walking through the `stack` [guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#user-guide), and also trying out the SublimeHaskell plugin.

I get as far as the [Curated Package Sets](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#curated-package-sets) section where `extra-deps` are introduced:

```
extra-deps:
- acme-missiles-0.3
```

The project builds correctly using `stack build`.

However when I edit `Lib.hs` using SublimeHaskell ...

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import Acme.Missiles

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = launchMissiles
```

... it can't find the `Acme.Missiles` module:

```
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0, Hints: 0, Uncategorized 0

Errors: 1

  /Users/guy_middleton/src/haskell/helloworld/src/Lib.hs: line 5, column 1:
    Error: Could not find module ‘Acme.Missiles’ Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Is there some configuration I can add to SublimeHaskell to find the extra deps?